# Debugging ExportTablesToExcelFiles Script for SPSS Statistics 23

Tags: vba, export, spss, winwrap

I am trying to run the IBM script **ExportTablesToExcelFiles** script (wwd version) for **SPSS Statistics 23** in **Windows 10**.

The script allows you to export SPSS output to individual Excel worksheets in a workbook.

I get this error: 
[image]

The script apparently cannot get past the first few lines:
[image]

In the SPSS output window, I receive "ERROR: (16305) No error.."

I tried the fix [PM40090: "ERROR : (16305) NO ERROR." RECEIVED WHEN RUNNING WINWRAP BASIC SCRIPT ON A 64-BIT IBM SPSS STATISTICS 19 CLIENT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM40090), but it did not work.

Has anyone resolved this issue in with SPSS 23 and Windows 10?

Comment: Did you add the reference to the project?

Comment: @litelite I have not done that and I am not sure what that means. Do I need to actually alter the script?

Comment: You have to add a _reference_ to spss to tell vba that these types exists, because they do not exists in the base language. However, i never used WinWrapIDE so i do not know how to do it. So you will have to check the documentation. This usually done in the project settings and usually require little to no modification of the code

Comment: OK thanks, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolved this issue after a day of searching and trying stuff.

Solution that worked for me was to re-register the spss*.tlb and the spsswin.dll located in C:\Program Files\Common Files\IBM\SPSS\COM.
The problem I had was a missing regtlibv12.exe which I hade to copy from a Win7.

- Copy the regtlibv12.exe from a Windows 7 located in C:\Windows.old\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319.
- Paste the regtlibv12.exe to the COM folder mentioned above.
- Open the Shell (CMD) and go to C:\Program Files\Common Files\IBM\SPSS\COM

  - Enter the following commands:

  regtlibv12.exe "C:\Program Files\Common Files\IBM\SPSS\COM\spssgctl.tlb"

  regtlibv12.exe "C:\Program Files\Common Files\IBM\SPSS\COM\spsspvt.tlb"

  regtlibv12.exe "C:\Program Files\Common Files\IBM\SPSS\COM\spssrtf.tlb"

  regtlibv12.exe "C:\Program Files\Common Files\IBM\SPSS\COM\spsswin.tlb"

  regtlibv12.exe "C:\Program Files\Common Files\IBM\SPSS\COM\treeview.tlb"

  regtlibv12.exe "C:\Program Files\Common Files\IBM\SPSS\COM\vischart.tlb"

  regsvr32 spsswin.dll

After this the scripts found the correct libraries / references again.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of incorrect installation of SPSS. Please uninstall and then re-install whole of the SPSS (ensuring SPSS created folders in AppData are also removed before installing again). This will get resolved. It did for me.

Thanks.